# Regular expression to parse and wrap certain tags in java

Tags: java, html, regex

I am trying to parse an html content and put  tags around the only text content and image content should be left as it is .
For example:

```
<span style="font-size:10pt;font-family:.SF NS Text;" class="left">hi<span style="font-weight:normal;font-style:normal;vertical-align:top;"><img border="0" src="file:///Users/EmoticonCool.png" alt="cool" title="cool" keybrd="8-)" width="18" height="18" src_data="file:///Users/EmoticonCool.png" /></span> test
</span>
```

I am expecting the output like below

```
<form><p><span color=\"color\">hi</span><img border="0" src="file:///Users/EmoticonCool.png" alt="cool" title="cool" keybrd="8-)" width="18" height="18" src_data="file:///Users/EmoticonCool.png" /></p><span color=\"color\">test</span></form>
```

I want to wrap all text content to wrap inside the span with some extra attribute and leave the img as its for further processing .

I wrote a small main to strip of all the styling and span (As i donot need any of styling)and give me by removing the html only img tags will be there

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class HTMLParser {


    private static List<String> EXCLUDED_TAGS = Arrays.asList(
        "(<span\\s*[^>]*>|</span>)",
        "(<b>|</b>)",
        "(<i>|</i>)",
        "(<u>|</u>)"
    );
    private static String teststring="<span style=\"font-size:10pt;font-family:.SF NS Text;\" class=\"left\">hi<span style=\"font-weight:normal;font-style:normal;vertical-align:top;\"><img border=\"0\" src=\"file:///Users/EmoticonCool.png\" alt=\"cool\" title=\"cool\" keybrd=\"8-)\" width=\"18\" height=\"18\" src_data=\"file:///Users/EmoticonCool.png\" /></span> test</span>";

    public static void main(String[] args) {


                EXCLUDED_TAGS.forEach(
                    re -> {
                        teststring = Pattern.compile(re, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.MULTILINE)
                            .matcher(teststring)
                            .replaceAll("");
                    });
System.out.println(teststring);
    }

}
```

I donot have any clue how can i add the span around the text now .Any clue on this will be helpful.

Comment: Can you consider using an HTML parser instead of regexps?

Comment: [Obligatory link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1732348/3788176)

Comment: I donot want to  add a dependency of html parser here .I know only span and img tags are going to come in html no other tags will be there